# STM32 HAL_Delay Hangs on HAL_GetTick()

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I saw this problem happened before too. Their solution was adding

```
void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    HAL_IncTick();
}
```

to stm32f4xx_it.c file.

I checked priority of the "system tick timer", it is 0. So it has highest priority as well.

Even blinky code is having same problem. Which it didnt have before.

It was automatically added at me already. Is there any other place i should look for this problem?

(It was working fine previously, I did not make any changes on the systick or clock.)
Thank you

Comment: not enough information.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? Stm32CubeMx?

Comment: I am using Linux PC. Compiler ist STM32CubeIde. Board is Nucleo-L476RG

Comment: I bet that the HAL function is called from the ISR. Am I right or wrong?